# Regular expression for search and replace latex eqno tag in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, latex

How to search and replace `\eqno(42)` with blankspace in MS Word?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no need for a regex with that string. Or do you mean a variable number of blank spaces?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I meant that there can be any number inside the brackets. Sorry for inaccurate question.

Answer (score 0):

- Updated answer

You can use Find and Replace to do that.  The caret plus Number symbol ^# will find any digit.

Ctrl H will open the dialog box.

In 'Find what:' Put \eqno(^#^#) (plus any blank spaces before or after that you want)

In 'Replace with:' type one blank space.

Click on 'Replace All'

The find digit (^#) command will find only one digit, not one number, so you may need to run this once each for parentheses containing a single digit (^#), double digit (^#^#), triple digit (^#^#^#) etc.

Before you move on, check to make sure you get the results you want.  You can undo (Ctrl Z) and adjust if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I meant that there can be any number inside the brackets. Question is not clear, sorry for that.